# Attaching events after Ajax load vs delegate events: what factors to consider?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please consider scenario: we load some HTML page using Ajax with bunch of buttons. We need to attach events to these buttons after load.

What factors should a developer consider when choosing between delegating events on container or attaching events after load?

I am asking this because I never know which method to use. I usually attach events after load because I can use extra data from Ajax response. But performance-wise which method is better? Are there well-known pros and cons to each approach's performance?

Examples:

## attaching events after load

```
var $cont = $(".container");

$.get("test.html", function(data) {
  $cont.html(data);     
  initEvents(); // normally I use this because I can use/pass extra data from response
});

var initEvents = function() {
    $cont.find('.my-button').click(function() {
        // ... magic ...
    });
    $cont.find('.my-other-button').click(function() {
        // ... magic ...
    });
}
```

## delegating events

```
var $cont = $(".container");   

$.get("test.html", function(data) {
  $cont.html(data);
});

$cont.on("click", ".my-button", function() {
  // ... magic ...
});

$cont.on("click", ".my-other-button", function() {
  // ... magic ...
});
```

Comment: Depends on the situation. I wouldn't use event delegating to bind a container that gets replaced with varying content (for example, the #main element of a SPA.) however i would use it for a container that gets replaced with similar content where the only thing changed was text, not the html or intent.

Comment: I've edited your question to try to save it from being closed as opinion-based. (I'm not sure I've done that, but that was my intent.) If you don't like my edits, feel free to revert them or change them further.

Comment: @apsillers your edit is spot on thanks

Answer (score 2):

The issue is not necessarily black or white.

To some extent, it's down to preference and opinion. I would normally favour delegating events as it means that, when the content is loaded - and, crucially, RE-loaded later, perhaps, as a result of filters - the events stuff is already active. Very clean.

Delegation also *usually* means a lighter workload for the browser. Rather than attach 100 events, just one is logged, and the event target evaluated when the event fires.

Furthermore, delegation can help you avoid the duplicated running of code. Say you had:

```
$.get('some_script.php').done(function() {
    $('.foo').on('click', function() { ... });
});
```

You're registering the event each and every time the content is loaded, whereas delegation means it could have run just once.

When not to delegate? Well, if your event-binding code is substantial or weighty, such that you may wish to defer its execution, there is an argument to do so until the content has loaded. This way you stagger the load weight of your page.

In short, in all but exceptional cases, I would suggest delegation.